# C# implementation not assignable to interface

Tags: c#, generics

So i got following interfaces:

```
public interface ICommand<TResult> { }
internal interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand, out TResult> where TCommand : ICommand<TResult> {
    TResult Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

and following commands:

```
public sealed class DisconnectCommand : ICommand<bool> { }
internal sealed class DisconnectCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<DisconnectCommand, bool> {
    bool Handle(DisconnectCommand command) => true
}
```

Now somewhere in my code in a facade for all the command handlers I have following function, in which I have all my command handlers at my disposal and I am able to find the correct one via reflection:

```
public TResult HandleCommand<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command);
```

Problem is, that I cannot assign any command handler to a variable of type interface

```
ICommandHandler<ICommandy<TResult>, TResult> selectedHandler = ...;
```

Even when I specifically try to do as follows the compiler tells me he cannot assign the type DisconnectedCommandHandler to ICommandHandler:

```
ICommandHandler<ICommand<bool>, bool> testHandler = new DisconnectCommandHandler();
```

I suspect that it has something to do with the usage of DisconnectCommand as the generic parameter of ICommandHandler instead of ICommand but I want to explicitly set that as it may occur happen that there are several layers of abstract classes in between. What is the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to create a command processor to dispatch all commands to their correct handler. You can't do this trying to assign the resulting command handler to an interface but you can use `dynamic` and since your command handler only has a `Handle` method you can be certain that using the method will always work. For complete example you can see [this blog post](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-query-side-of-my-architecture/) that explains how to do what you're trying. And just for reference here is the `QueryProcessor` from that post.

```
sealed class QueryProcessor : IQueryProcessor
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public QueryProcessor(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public TResult Process<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)
            .MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));

        dynamic handler = container.GetInstance(handlerType);

        return handler.Handle((dynamic)query);
    }
}
```

Also, if your trying to implement some kind of CQRS then what you're calling a `Command` should be called a `Query` since you're returning a result.

Comment: yes thank you I already had this implemented myself but I wanted to try go without dynamics anyways.  Thanks for the answer tho

Comment: And no a command should not be called a Query. This is an explicit decision in our architecture and commands either return bool or bool? to indicate success, whereas queries will actually return something. There will be several precautions to prevent queries (and their handlers) from having any side effects in this SDK, which is also a requirement from one of our customers.